# issue with dependency injection with interface

Tags: go

I have the package that provides some work with tcp connections, basically something like:

```
package connpool

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type ConnPool struct{}

func (pool *ConnPool) GetConn() Conn {
    return Conn{}
}

func (pool *ConnPool) ReleaseConnection(conn Conn)  {

}

type Conn struct{}

func (c Conn) FetchUrl(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return body, nil
}
```

then i try to use it in another package, but wrapping it by interface, because i want substitute this package in test environment with fake connpool

```
package main

import (
    "connpool"
    "fmt"
)

func onlyDependencyOnConnPool() *connpool.ConnPool {
    return &connpool.ConnPool{}
}

type ConnPoolInterface interface {
    GetConn() ConnInterface
    ReleaseConnection(ConnInterface)
}

type ConnInterface interface {
    FetchUrl(string) ([]byte, error)
}

type Fetcher struct{}

func (f Fetcher) Fetch(cPool ConnPoolInterface) error {
    conn := cPool.GetConn()
    defer cPool.ReleaseConnection(conn)
    body, err := conn.FetchUrl("http://localhost:9200")
    fmt.Println("body: ", string(body))
    return err
}

func main() {
    pool := onlyDependencyOnConnPool()
    f := Fetcher{}
    f.Fetch(pool)
}
```

but it will return error on compile:

```
./main.go:34: cannot use pool (type *connpool.ConnPool) as type ConnPoolInterface in argument to f.Fetch:
    *connpool.ConnPool does not implement ConnPoolInterface (wrong type for GetConn method)
        have GetConn() connpool.Conn
        want GetConn() ConnInterface
```

Is the any way to wrap this dependency by interface without connpool import in every file?

I need it just to mock the http requests in my test environment, something like this(if i will implement interfaces in the connpool package i will have to implement every mock struct in it, it look like some kind of mess):

```
package main

import(
  "testing"
)

type FakeConnPool struct{}

func (pool *FakeConnPool) GetConn() FakeConn {
    return FakeConn{}
}

func (pool *FakeConnPool) ReleaseConnection(conn FakeConn)  {
}

type FakeConn struct{}

func (c FakeConn) FetchUrl(url string) ([]byte, error) {
  println(url)
  body := []byte(`{"status" : 200}`)
    return body, nil
}

func changeDependency() ConnPoolInterface {
  return &FakeConnPool{}
}
func TestBaz(t *testing.T)  {
  pool := changeDependency()
    f := Fetcher{}
    err := f.Fetch(pool)
  if err != nil {
    t.Errorf("error")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first step just change your declaration of `GetConn` slightly to the following:

```
func (pool *ConnPool) GetConn() ConnInterface {  // Conn -> ConnInterface
    return Conn{}
}
```

That should fulfill the interface of `ConnPoolInterface`. You would probably have to rearrange your code slightly to avoid circular dependencies after that.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i can't do this: connpool package do not contain that interface, by adding it we will change nothing, it will become pool.ConnInterface in main packege, not ConnInterface, so we will still have  the leaky dependency

Comment: To me it appears that the right way to do it would be to put the interfaces in the same package that the original implementation is located (`connpool`). Or are you unable to modify the `connpool` package? I don't really understand what you mean by leaky dependency in this case. If you have something against mixing implementation and interface in the same package you can put the interfaces in their own packages. I don't really see the point in that though.

Comment: well, i'm not very eloquent, i just added new info into the question with test example, hope it will explain why i want declare interfaces in main package, thanks for you attention

Comment: Sorry, I don't really think I understand your problem. If you are going to mock the interfaces you'll have to implement them. Right? I might understand what you want to do though. You want all of your methods on the connection pools to take and return concrete types of connections while still implementing the `ConnPoolInterface`. Is that right? I don't think that's possible. I still think that having the interfaces in  connpool is the right thing to do. After all you probably don't want to have everything in `main` as your program grows.

Comment: For the tests you can add a couple of helper functions and structs to create mock connection pools and connections. These can then be used across tests to reduce duplication.